# MySQL Slave not Replicating

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

I have set up MySQL master/slave replication for 2 servers before without problems, I usually follow the great documentation on the MySQL website [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html).  However this time I have set it up and everything looks like it should be working, but the slave is not updating with new data from the master.  I will show some output from both the master and the server.

Master (IP:10.1.1.21)

```
show processlist
```

> '107', 'repl', '10.1.1.22:60686', NULL, 'Binlog Dump', '523', 'Has
>   sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated', NULL

```
show master status
```

> 'mysql-bin.000280', '10494', 'joomla', 'mysql'

Slave (IP:10.1.1.22)

```
show processlist
```

> '9', 'system user', '', NULL, 'Connect', '625', 'Waiting for master to send event', NULL
>
> '10', 'system user', '', NULL, 'Connect', '10', 'Has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it', NULL

```
show slave status
```

> 'Waiting for master to send event', '10.1.1.21', 'repl', '3306', '60', 'mysql-bin.000280', '14029', 'tim-Dell-DM061-relay-bin.000002', '14174', 'mysql-bin.000280', 'Yes', 'Yes', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '0', '14029', '14338', 'None', '', '0', 'No', '', '', '', '', '', '0', 'No', '0', '', '0', ''

The way I tested to see if it was working was to create a table on the master.  I did this and this new table did not propagate to the slave.  I did check the relay binary log, and it did have a lot of updates in it.  This is a website database, and I just checked it the # of hits are propagating to the slave, so it seems to be working a little.

Creating a table is not propagating, and also i tried inserting some data into a test table that existing when I did the initial data sync to the slave, this does not propagate to the slave either.

Any ideas of how I can debug this further??

Thanks!

EDIT:

the `show global variables like 'replicate%'` returns 2 columns: "Variable_name", "Value".  There aren't any rows of data.

Comment: Could you also post the output of the following command: `show global variables like 'replicate%` (executed on the slave).

Comment: @DimitreRadoulov I posted the output above, thanks!

Comment: Hi @jeffery_the_wind, see Rolando's comments below - the issue may be related to the settings of *binlog-do/ignore-db*.

Comment: Yes they are related to the binlog-do-db settings, thanks!

Comment: This should resolve itself, but it can take many hours

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In our `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` I noticed you have this

```
'mysql-bin.000280', '10494', 'joomla', 'mysql'
```

I cringe when someone uses binlog-do-db. [**Here is why**](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/).

[There is an old bug report for MySQL 4.0 that I do not fully believe was fixed](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6749).

Comment: Good point! Even if, given the post format it's not immediately obvious if *joomla* is in *Binlog_Do_DB* or both *joomla* and *mysql* are in *Binlog_Ignore_DB*.

Comment: Yes great point.  Actually my replication was working, but since I am using binlog-do-db my `create table` queries would not propagate unless I `use` the right schema.  Thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA

Answer (score 8):

Apparently your bin position on the master is currently 10494 and your slave sees your Read_Master_Log_Pos as 14029.

So your slave thinks it is ahead of the master in log position, and waiting for the master to have new data.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. How do we fix this?